# archive-product page not working

Tags: woocommerce

i am trying to use woocommerce in my theme. i had copied woocommerce template file in my theme->woocommerce folder but still my changes not showing. even i was trying in plugin code but i had not seen any changes.
This is my archive-product coding

```
<?php
/**
 * The Template for displaying product archives, including the main shop page which is a post type archive
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/archive-product.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see         https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version     3.3.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

get_header( 'shop' );

/**
 * Hook: woocommerce_before_main_content.
 *
 * @hooked woocommerce_output_content_wrapper - 10 (outputs opening divs for the content)
 * @hooked woocommerce_breadcrumb - 20
 * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::generate_website_data() - 30
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content' );

?>
<header class="woocommerce-products-header">
    <?php if ( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_show_page_title', true ) ) : ?>
        <h1 class="woocommerce-products-header__title page-title"><?php woocommerce_page_title(); ?></h1>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php
    /**
     * Hook: woocommerce_archive_description.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description - 10
     * @hooked woocommerce_product_archive_description - 10
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description' );
    ?>
</header>
<?php

if ( have_posts() ) {

    /**
     * Hook: woocommerce_before_shop_loop.
     *
     * @hooked wc_print_notices - 10
     * @hooked woocommerce_result_count - 20
     * @hooked woocommerce_catalog_ordering - 30
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop' );

    woocommerce_product_loop_start();

    if ( wc_get_loop_prop( 'total' ) ) {
        while ( have_posts() ) {
            the_post();

            /**
             * Hook: woocommerce_shop_loop.
             *
             * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::generate_product_data() - 10
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop' );

            wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
        }
    }

    woocommerce_product_loop_end();

    /**
     * Hook: woocommerce_after_shop_loop.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_pagination - 10
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop' );
} else {
    /**
     * Hook: woocommerce_no_products_found.
     *
     * @hooked wc_no_products_found - 10
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_no_products_found' );
}

/**
 * Hook: woocommerce_after_main_content.
 *
 * @hooked woocommerce_output_content_wrapper_end - 10 (outputs closing divs for the content)
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content' );

/**
 * Hook: woocommerce_sidebar.
 *
 * @hooked woocommerce_get_sidebar - 10
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_sidebar' );

get_footer( 'shop' );
?>
```

This is my function file. you can check , i am very confuse...

```
<?php
/**
 * herbal functions and definitions
 *
 * Set up the theme and provides some helper functions, which are used in the
 * theme as custom template tags. Others are attached to action and filter
 * hooks in WordPress to change core functionality.
 *
 * When using a child theme you can override certain functions (those wrapped
 * in a function_exists() call) by defining them first in your child theme's
 * functions.php file. The child theme's functions.php file is included before
 * the parent theme's file, so the child theme functions would be used.
 *
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes
 *
 * Functions that are not pluggable (not wrapped in function_exists()) are
 * instead attached to a filter or action hook.
 *
 * For more information on hooks, actions, and filters,
 * {@link https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API}
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage herbal
 * @since herbal
 */

/**
 * Twenty Sixteen only works in WordPress 4.4 or later.
 */
if ( version_compare( $GLOBALS['wp_version'], '4.4-alpha', '<' ) ) {
    require get_template_directory() . '/inc/back-compat.php';
}

if ( ! function_exists( 'twentysixteen_setup' ) ) :
/**
 * Sets up theme defaults and registers support for various WordPress features.
 *
 * Note that this function is hooked into the after_setup_theme hook, which
 * runs before the init hook. The init hook is too late for some features, such
 * as indicating support for post thumbnails.
 *
 * Create your own twentysixteen_setup() function to override in a child theme.
 *
 * @since Twenty Sixteen 1.0
 */
function twentysixteen_setup() {
    /*
     * Make theme available for translation.
     * Translations can be filed at WordPress.org. See: https://translate.wordpress.org/projects/wp-themes/twentysixteen
     * If you're building a theme based on Twenty Sixteen, use a find and replace
     * to change 'twentysixteen' to the name of your theme in all the template files
     */
    load_theme_textdomain( 'twentysixteen' );

    // Add default posts and comments RSS feed links to head.
    add_theme_support( 'automatic-feed-links' );

    /*
     * Let WordPress manage the document title.
     * By adding theme support, we declare that this theme does not use a
     * hard-coded <title> tag in the document head, and expect WordPress to
     * provide it for us.
     */
    add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );

    /*
     * Enable support for custom logo.
     *
     *  @since Twenty Sixteen 1.2
     */
    add_theme_support( 'custom-logo', array(
        'height'      => 240,
        'width'       => 240,
        'flex-height' => true,
    ) );

    /*
     * Enable support for Post Thumbnails on posts and pages.
     *
     * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_theme_support#Post_Thumbnails
     */
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
    set_post_thumbnail_size( 1200, 9999 );

    // This theme uses wp_nav_menu() in two locations.
    register_nav_menus( array(
        'primary' => __( 'Primary Menu', 'twentysixteen' ),
        'social'  => __( 'Social Links Menu', 'twentysixteen' ),
    ) );

    /*
     * Switch default core markup for search form, comment form, and comments
     * to output valid HTML5.
     */
    add_theme_support( 'html5', array(
        'search-form',
        'comment-form',
        'comment-list',
        'gallery',
        'caption',
    ) );

    /*
     * Enable support for Post Formats.
     *
     * See: https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Formats
     */
    add_theme_support( 'post-formats', array(
        'aside',
        'image',
        'video',
        'quote',
        'link',
        'gallery',
        'status',
        'audio',
        'chat',
    ) );

    /*
     * This theme styles the visual editor to resemble the theme style,
     * specifically font, colors, icons, and column width.
     */
    add_editor_style( array( 'css/editor-style.css', twentysixteen_fonts_url() ) );

    // Indicate widget sidebars can use selective refresh in the Customizer.
    add_theme_support( 'customize-selective-refresh-widgets' );
}
endif; // twentysixteen_setup
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'twentysixteen_setup' );

/**
 * Sets the content width in pixels, based on the theme's design and stylesheet.
 *
 * Priority 0 to make it available to lower priority callbacks.
 *
 * @global int $content_width
 *
 * @since Twenty Sixteen 1.0
 */
function twentysixteen_content_width() {
    $GLOBALS['content_width'] = apply_filters( 'twentysixteen_content_width', 840 );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'twentysixteen_content_width', 0 );

/**
 * Registers a widget area.
 *
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_sidebar/
 *
 * @since Twenty Sixteen 1.0
 */
function twentysixteen_widgets_init() {
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => __( 'Sidebar', 'twentysixteen' ),
        'id'            => 'sidebar-1',
        'description'   => __( 'Add widgets here to appear in your sidebar.', 'twentysixteen' ),
        'before_widget' => '<section id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget'  => '</section>',
        'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title'   => '</h2>',
    ) );

    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => __( 'Content Bottom 1', 'twentysixteen' ),
        'id'            => 'sidebar-2',
        'description'   => __( 'Appears at the bottom of the content on posts and pages.', 'twentysixteen' ),
        'before_widget' => '<section id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget'  => '</section>',
        'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title'   => '</h2>',
    ) );

    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => __( 'Content Bottom 2', 'twentysixteen' ),
        'id'            => 'sidebar-3',
        'description'   => __( 'Appears at the bottom of the content on posts and pages.', 'twentysixteen' ),
        'before_widget' => '<section id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget'  => '</section>',
        'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title'   => '</h2>',
    ) );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'twentysixteen_widgets_init' );

if ( ! function_exists( 'twentysixteen_fonts_url' ) ) :
/**
 * Register Google fonts for Twenty Sixteen.
 *
 * Create your own twentysixteen_fonts_url() function to override in a child theme.
 *
 * @since Twenty Sixteen 1.0
 *
 * @return string Google fonts URL for the theme.
 */
function twentysixteen_fonts_url() {
    $fonts_url = '';
    $fonts     = array();
    $subsets   = 'latin,latin-ext';

    /* translators: If there are characters in your language that are not supported by Merriweather, translate this to 'off'. Do not translate into your own language. */
    if ( 'off' !== _x( 'on', 'Merriweather font: on or off', 'twentysixteen' ) ) {
        $fonts[] = 'Merriweather:400,700,900,400italic,700italic,900italic';
    }

    /* translators: If there are characters in your language that are not supported by Montserrat, translate this to 'off'. Do not translate into your own language. */
    if ( 'off' !== _x( 'on', 'Montserrat font: on or off', 'twentysixteen' ) ) {
        $fonts[] = 'Montserrat:400,700';
    }

    /* translators: If there are characters in your language that are not supported by Inconsolata, translate this to 'off'. Do not translate into your own language. */
    if ( 'off' !== _x( 'on', 'Inconsolata font: on or off', 'twentysixteen' ) ) {
        $fonts[] = 'Inconsolata:400';
    }

    if ( $fonts ) {
        $fonts_url = add_query_arg( array(
            'family' => urlencode( implode( '|', $fonts ) ),
            'subset' => urlencode( $subsets ),
        ), 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css' );
    }

    return $fonts_url;
}
endif;

/**
 * Handles JavaScript detection.
 *
 * Adds a `js` class to the root `<html>` element when JavaScript is detected.
 *
 * @since Twenty Sixteen 1.0
 */
function twentysixteen_javascript_detection() {
    echo "<script>(function(html){html.className = html.className.replace(/\bno-js\b/,'js')})(document.documentElement);</script>\n";
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'twentysixteen_javascript_detection', 0 );

/**
 * Enqueues scripts and styles.
 *
 * @since Twenty Sixteen 1.0
 */
function twentysixteen_scripts() {
    // Add custom fonts, used in the main stylesheet.
    wp_enqueue_style( 'twentysixteen-fonts', twentysixteen_fonts_url(), array(), null );

    // Add Genericons, used in the main stylesheet.
    wp_enqueue_style( 'genericons', get_template_directory_uri() . '/genericons/genericons.css', array(), '3.4.1' );

    // Theme stylesheet.
    wp_enqueue_style( 'twentysixteen-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );

    // Load the Internet Explorer specific stylesheet.
    wp_enqueue_style( 'twentysixteen-ie', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/ie.css', array( 'twentysixteen-style' ), '20160816' );
    wp_style_add_data( 'twentysixteen-ie', 'conditional', 'lt IE 10' );

    // Load the Internet Explorer 8 specific stylesheet.
    wp_enqueue_style( 'twentysixteen-ie8', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/ie8.css', array( 'twentysixteen-style' ), '20160816' );
    wp_style_add_data( 'twentysixteen-ie8', 'conditional', 'lt IE 9' );

    // Load the Internet Explorer 7 specific stylesheet.
    wp_enqueue_style( 'twentysixteen-ie7', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/ie7.css', array( 'twentysixteen-style' ), '20160816' );
    wp_style_add_data( 'twentysixteen-ie7', 'conditional', 'lt IE 8' );

    // Load the html5 shiv.
    wp_enqueue_script( 'twentysixteen-html5', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/html5.js', array(), '3.7.3' );
    wp_script_add_data( 'twentysixteen-html5', 'conditional', 'lt IE 9' );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'twentysixteen-skip-link-focus-fix', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/skip-link-focus-fix.js', array(), '20160816', true );

    if ( is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
    }

    if ( is_singular() && wp_attachment_is_image() ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'twentysixteen-keyboard-image-navigation', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/keyboard-image-navigation.js', array( 'jquery' ), '20160816' );
    }

    wp_enqueue_script( 'twentysixteen-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/functions.js', array( 'jquery' ), '20160816', true );

    wp_localize_script( 'twentysixteen-script', 'screenReaderText', array(
        'expand'   => __( 'expand child menu', 'twentysixteen' ),
        'collapse' => __( 'collapse child menu', 'twentysixteen' ),
    ) );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'twentysixteen_scripts' );

/**
 * Adds custom classes to the array of body classes.
 *
 * @since Twenty Sixteen 1.0
 *
 * @param array $classes Classes for the body element.
 * @return array (Maybe) filtered body classes.
 */
function twentysixteen_body_classes( $classes ) {
    // Adds a class of custom-background-image to sites with a custom background image.
    if ( get_background_image() ) {
        $classes[] = 'custom-background-image';
    }

    // Adds a class of group-blog to sites with more than 1 published author.
    if ( is_multi_author() ) {
        $classes[] = 'group-blog';
    }

    // Adds a class of no-sidebar to sites without active sidebar.
    if ( ! is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ) ) {
        $classes[] = 'no-sidebar';
    }

    // Adds a class of hfeed to non-singular pages.
    if ( ! is_singular() ) {
        $classes[] = 'hfeed';
    }

    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'body_class', 'twentysixteen_body_classes' );

/**
 * Converts a HEX value to RGB.
 *
 * @since Twenty Sixteen 1.0
 *
 * @param string $color The original color, in 3- or 6-digit hexadecimal form.
 * @return array Array containing RGB (red, green, and blue) values for the given
 *               HEX code, empty array otherwise.
 */
function twentysixteen_hex2rgb( $color ) {
    $color = trim( $color, '#' );

    if ( strlen( $color ) === 3 ) {
        $r = hexdec( substr( $color, 0, 1 ).substr( $color, 0, 1 ) );
        $g = hexdec( substr( $color, 1, 1 ).substr( $color, 1, 1 ) );
        $b = hexdec( substr( $color, 2, 1 ).substr( $color, 2, 1 ) );
    } else if ( strlen( $color ) === 6 ) {
        $r = hexdec( substr( $color, 0, 2 ) );
        $g = hexdec( substr( $color, 2, 2 ) );
        $b = hexdec( substr( $color, 4, 2 ) );
    } else {
        return array();
    }

    return array( 'red' => $r, 'green' => $g, 'blue' => $b );
}

/**
 * Custom template tags for this theme.
 */
require get_template_directory() . '/inc/template-tags.php';

/**
 * Customizer additions.
 */
require get_template_directory() . '/inc/customizer.php';

/**
 * Add custom image sizes attribute to enhance responsive image functionality
 * for content images
 *
 * @since Twenty Sixteen 1.0
 *
 * @param string $sizes A source size value for use in a 'sizes' attribute.
 * @param array  $size  Image size. Accepts an array of width and height
 *                      values in pixels (in that order).
 * @return string A source size value for use in a content image 'sizes' attribute.
 */
function twentysixteen_content_image_sizes_attr( $sizes, $size ) {
    $width = $size[0];

    if ( 840 <= $width ) {
        $sizes = '(max-width: 709px) 85vw, (max-width: 909px) 67vw, (max-width: 1362px) 62vw, 840px';
    }

    if ( 'page' === get_post_type() ) {
        if ( 840 > $width ) {
            $sizes = '(max-width: ' . $width . 'px) 85vw, ' . $width . 'px';
        }
    } else {
        if ( 840 > $width && 600 <= $width ) {
            $sizes = '(max-width: 709px) 85vw, (max-width: 909px) 67vw, (max-width: 984px) 61vw, (max-width: 1362px) 45vw, 600px';
        } elseif ( 600 > $width ) {
            $sizes = '(max-width: ' . $width . 'px) 85vw, ' . $width . 'px';
        }
    }

    return $sizes;
}
add_filter( 'wp_calculate_image_sizes', 'twentysixteen_content_image_sizes_attr', 10 , 2 );

/**
 * Add custom image sizes attribute to enhance responsive image functionality
 * for post thumbnails
 *
 * @since Twenty Sixteen 1.0
 *
 * @param array $attr Attributes for the image markup.
 * @param int   $attachment Image attachment ID.
 * @param array $size Registered image size or flat array of height and width dimensions.
 * @return array The filtered attributes for the image markup.
 */
function twentysixteen_post_thumbnail_sizes_attr( $attr, $attachment, $size ) {
    if ( 'post-thumbnail' === $size ) {
        if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ) ) {
            $attr['sizes'] = '(max-width: 709px) 85vw, (max-width: 909px) 67vw, (max-width: 984px) 60vw, (max-width: 1362px) 62vw, 840px';
        } else {
            $attr['sizes'] = '(max-width: 709px) 85vw, (max-width: 909px) 67vw, (max-width: 1362px) 88vw, 1200px';
        }
    }
    return $attr;
}
add_filter( 'wp_get_attachment_image_attributes', 'twentysixteen_post_thumbnail_sizes_attr', 10 , 3 );

/**
 * Modifies tag cloud widget arguments to display all tags in the same font size
 * and use list format for better accessibility.
 *
 * @since Twenty Sixteen 1.1
 *
 * @param array $args Arguments for tag cloud widget.
 * @return array The filtered arguments for tag cloud widget.
 */
function twentysixteen_widget_tag_cloud_args( $args ) {
    $args['largest']  = 1;
    $args['smallest'] = 1;
    $args['unit']     = 'em';
    $args['format']   = 'list'; 

    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'widget_tag_cloud_args', 'twentysixteen_widget_tag_cloud_args' );

remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );




 function adver() {
    $args = array(
      'label' => 'Advertisement',
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'adver'),
        'taxonomies' => array('topics' ),
        'query_var' => true,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-tag',
        'supports' => array(
            'title',
            'thumbnail',
            'editor',
            'experts',)
        );
    register_post_type( 'adver', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'adver' );








 function serv() {
    $args = array(
      'label' => 'services',
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'serv'),
        'taxonomies' => array('topics' ),
        'query_var' => true,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-tag',
        'supports' => array(
            'title',
            'thumbnail',
            'editor',
            'experts',)
        );
    register_post_type( 'serv', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'serv' );
```

Comment: What guide have you already read about setting up woocomerce template?

Comment: I search many solutions in google..

Comment: You don't need to 'search many'.... just follow official documentation. Have you enabled new template in your admin panel? It's not only about copying it

Comment: i had installed both (theme + woocommerce plugin) 2 days ago. i am not sure its latest or not.but i downloaded it from google

Comment: my main issue is that archive-product page does not accept my changes..